# Row to not visible if null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using windows form to build an application using `datagridview`. Every data grid contains an empty row at the top and I suspect that it is the way that I am populating them but as I am coming to the end, I am reluctant to change any of my code as I am a beginner.

Is there a simple way to check if a row if empty, then set that to not visible?

The code that I am using:

```
private void displayInGrid_Customers(string sqlcmd)
{
    customersDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

    connect.Open();

    command.Connection = connect;
    command.CommandText = sqlcmd;

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    customersDataGridView.Rows.Add();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        DataGridViewRow rowadd = (DataGridViewRow)customersDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();

        rowadd.Cells[0].Value = reader["Customer_ID"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[1].Value = reader["Forename"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[2].Value = reader["Surname"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[3].Value = reader["Address"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[4].Value = reader["Town"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[5].Value = reader["Postcode"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[6].Value = reader["Date_Of_Birth"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[7].Value = reader["Phone_Number"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[8].Value = reader["Email"].ToString();
        rowadd.Cells[9].Value = reader["Current_Rental"].ToString();
        this.customersDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        customersDataGridView.Rows.Add(rowadd);
    }
    reader.Close();
    connect.Close();
}

private void button_view_all_customers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT CUSTOMERS.Customer_ID, CUSTOMERS.Forename, CUSTOMERS.Surname, CUSTOMERS.Address, "
                          + "CUSTOMERS.Town, CUSTOMERS.Postcode, CUSTOMERS.Date_Of_Birth, CUSTOMERS.Phone_Number, CUSTOMERS.Email, CUSTOMERS.Current_Rental "
                          + "from CUSTOMERS LEFT JOIN STOCK ON CUSTOMERS.Current_Rental = STOCK.Product_ID";
    string cmd = command.CommandText;
    displayInGrid_Customers(cmd);
}
```

Comment: you can check if the the row elements are null before adding it to `DataGridView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But before that, you have to check your sql statement, why you have empty rows result.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    DataGridViewRow rowadd = (DataGridViewRow)customersDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reader["Customer_ID"].ToString()))
    {
         rowadd.Cells[0].Value = reader["Customer_ID"].ToString();
         //Others Stuff
         //...
         this.customersDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
         customersDataGridView.Rows.Add(rowadd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip. I am a little unsure how to implement this exactly? Is it possible that the rows.clone is causing the issue?

Comment: i think is not. the cause of the issue is your sql statement. try to double check.